# Summing Dynamic Range Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sum values in an entire column which is not fixed.

```
Sub CTG()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim PreviousData As Long
Dim MySum As Double, ColLetter As String

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly")
PreviousData = sht.Cells(2, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, PreviousData).Address, "$")(1)
 

MySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range("C:C"))

'MsgBox "The total of the ranges is " & MySum

End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is to convert

```
MySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range("C:C"))
```

into

```
MySum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(sht.Range("ColLetter :ColLetter"))
```

and I tried in several ways but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `sht.Range(ColLetter & ":" & ColLetter)`. Or `sht.Columns(PreviousData)`.

Comment: Or you could use  Table and structured references; or add a Totals row to the table. You don't even need to use VBA, although you could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sum of a Column

- The following sums up the values in the column before the last non-empty column calculated in the second row.
- You have to know that `Columns("C") = Columns(3) = Range("C:C")`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SumOfColumn()
    
    Dim MySum As Double
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Weekly")
        Dim blCol As Long ' Column Before the Last Column
        blCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
        If blCol = 0 Then
            MsgBox "There is no column before column ""A"".", _
                vbCritical, "Sum of Column"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        MySum = Application.Sum(.Columns(blCol))
    End With
    
    MsgBox "The column's total is '" & MySum & "'.", _
        vbInformation, "Sum of Column"

End Sub
```

- This has been addressed by BigBen in the comments (with `sht.Columns(PreviousData)` e.g. `sht.Columns(3)`).